# CSS - When changing a square image in a div to a different file, it affects my responsiveness

Tags: css

I created a page using a square filler image but when it came time to change it to the actual image I needed, when I switched to the new file, it affected the spacing and responsiveness of a section situated to the left of it. I keep switching back to the filler image and the problem goes away. I even made the replacement the same dimension of the filler image, and it didn't seem to do anything. I've never seen a problem like this before as both images are square.

https://jsfiddle.net/jmbv61dv/ I'm trying to replace the image in the first figure "far-alone.png" ...Its affecting the "side-logo.png" directly to the left..there are media queries in there as well but I don't think they have much to do with it

Also to add, the "far-alone.png" image file was really big, like 10X10 inches and around a meg in size. The new image I wanted to replace it with was a fraction of the file size, around 33k.

```
    <div id="sidebar"> 

        <div id="sidelogo"> 

            <a href src="index.html"><img src="assets/images/side-logo.png" alt="Aztech Records logo."></a>

        </div>

        <div id="dropdown">
            <button id="menu">☰</button>
            <nav>
                <a href="index.html" class="selected">Home</a>
                <a href="#">Our&nbsp;Story</a>
                <a href="#">Artists</a>
                <a href="#">Releases</a>
                <a href="#">Connect</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

<div id="content">

    <figure>
        <figcaption><span id="headline">RELEASE:</span> FORTE - LOUDER</figcaption>
        <img src="assets/images/far-alone.png" alt="FORTE - LOUDER">
        <h3>Forte dives deep and dark with this minimal 170 BPM masterpiece.</h3>
        <a id="soundcloud" href="http://soundcloud.com/">SOUNDCLOUD</a>
        <a id="spotify" href="http://spotify.com/">SPOTIFY</a>
    </figure>
```

Comment: Please provide a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jmbv61dv/ I'm trying to replace the image in the first figure "far-alone.png" ...Its affecting the "Aztech records Logo" directly to the left..there are media queries in there as well but I don't think they have much to do with it